# Special characters from $_GET using php

Tags: php

I'm trying to get text entered from url

my php contains

```
<?php
    $GET = rawurlencode($_GET[test]);
    print urldecode($GET);
?>
```

my text http://test.com/forum/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=27&extra=page%3D1

but it won't get the whole url... please help how to get full url

---edit--- 
to make my question more clearly

here is what i'll input in the url

```
http://test.com/redirect.php?test=http://test.com/forum/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=27&extra=page%3D1
```

and i want to get

```
http://test.com/forum/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=27&extra=page%3D1
```

Comment: you mean $_GET['test']

Comment: Check the `$_SERVER` super global, the entire url will never be found in `$_GET`, that's only for the erm... GET parameters

Comment: no i'm trying to get the url after ?test=

Answer (score 0):

your code can work normally, but I think there's a problem with `$_GET[test]` since it should be

```
$_GET['test']
```

Answer (score 0):

May be it will be helpfull

```
    <?php
     $uri=rawurldecode($_GET['test']);
     echo $uri;
```

Comment: hi i edited the first post to show what exactly i want
thanks!

Comment: hi thats what i have in the first post but it does not get the whole url

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, needed some string manipulation

```
<?php

$URL='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$pieces = explode("?test=", $URL);
echo $pieces[1];
?>
```